# During cabal-install "the impossible happened", should I let it keep trying?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

Is there any point to letting `cabal-install` try to keep building a package if, at some point in the process, I see this:

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
    ...some error...

...continues with build for a long time...

...eventual message: [x] failed to install
```

or should I just kill the process and try to solve the error?

Comment: I'd need to see more context, but this just means that one specific package failed to build.  Any packages not downstream of the one that failed will still build just fine.

Comment: What version of GHC are you using, and what exactly was the panic message?

Comment: @user5402 7.6.2, 7.6.3 both give variations of this error for various packages. But I'm trying to develop on an ARM machine, so I'm a bit more prone to 'impossible' things happening, I guess.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that one specific package failed to build.  Any packages not downstream of the one that failed will still build correctly.